# Pattern Using for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

I have to print the following pattern using for loop only.
[image: Required pattern]

I have written the following code which gives me till the the numbers increment. How can I decrement then in the other half.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x,r;
    for(r=1;r<5;r++)
    {
        for(x=3;x>=r;x--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        for(x=1;x<=r;x++)
        {
            printf("%d",x);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just add a second loop from r-1 to 1?

```
for (x = r - 1; x > 0; x--)
{
    printf("%d",x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Added one more loop

```
    for(x=1;x<=(r-1);x++)
    {
        printf("%d",x);
    }
```

whole code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int x,r;
for(r=1;r<5;r++)
{
    for(x=3;x>=r;x--)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }

    for(x=1;x<=r;x++)
    {
        printf("%d",x);
    }

    for(x=1;x<=(r-1);x++)
    {
        printf("%d",x);
    }


    printf("\n");
}
return 0;}
```

code running at http://codepad.org/oAdx20ai