# Pyramid Pattern in Java - Getting the Numbers Right

Tags: java

I'm trying to generate the loop below:

```
   1
  121
 12321
1234321
```

The loop is working as expected, but the numbers are not displaying properly. The loop is created for flexible usage if there is a constant variable to be input into the outer loop.

Right now, the output is:

```
   1   
  123  
 12345 
1234567
```

```
// line loop
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int line = 1; line <= 4; line++) {
        // space loop
        for (int space = 1; space <= -1 * line + 4; space++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        // number loop
        for (int num = 1; num <= 2 * line - 1; num++) {
            System.out.print(num);
        }

        // space loop
        for (int space = 1; space <= -1 * line + 4; space++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: What output are you seeing?

Comment: @MrLucky how is that matching with your expected output?

Comment: Why do you think you're getting that output? This looks like homework, so it's best we walk you through this.

Comment: Try `System.out.print(Math.min(num, 2 * line - num));`

Comment: Can you tell which part of your code might have a problem then?

Comment: Its not assignment. I'm trying to learn something that i'm weak at. The output is taken from here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277252/pattern-using-for-loop

Comment: Source aside, why do you think you're getting an output which only increases each integer, rather than rises and falls?

Comment: Because i'm using the num variable which is based on the calculation with the line variable which generate in this order.. 

1 number --> 1
3 numbers --> 123

etc

Comment: You have the right idea with 3 nested loops, however your last "space loop" is unnecessary. You could instead turn that loop into your "descending integers" loop / have it taking care of the 2nd half of each line.

Comment: Guys i'm not looking for answers. I want to know what is going on.

Comment: A debugger is your best friend in such situations.

Comment: Get rid of your second space loop and turn your "number loop" into _two_ number loops. Use "Number Loop 1" to count up, and use "Number Loop 2" to count down, all on the same line

Comment: How do you guys visualize the output ? I may have 3 loops done correctly. But the number calculation or methods is wrong. Anyway to improve on this?

Comment: MrLucky, completely remove the 2nd loop space and run the program again. You will see that you don't need it. 

At that point, take your number loop and cut it in half. Have one loop print half the numbers in ascending order, then have the 2nd loop print the other half in descending order..

Comment: Removed it. But is the second loop necessary if we can use one loop to complete this?

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // line loop
    for (int line = 1; line <= 4; line++) {
        // space loop
        for (int space = 1; space <= -1 * line + 4; space++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        // number loop
        for (int num = 1; num <= 2 * line - 1; num++) {
            if (num > (int) (2 * line) / 2) {
                System.out.print(((int) (2 * line)) - num);
            } else {
                System.out.print(num);
            }
        }

        // space loop
        for (int space = 1; space <= -1 * line + 4; space++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Explanation:

Iteration  = `num` var of the "number loop"

Cycles =  the `2 * line` part of the code, should be always an odd number.

when the Iteration int is greater than the next int starting from the half of the cycles (should be a float, so we need the next int), the Cycles int minus the iteration int should be print so our output starts printing in decreasing order.

Comment: Do you think the last space loop is important? In addition to that change, offer some explanation to OP.

Comment: That explanation could use some elaboration.

Comment: I kind of suck at explanations, they're really hard for me.

Comment: Hi Cheloideman,

Thanks for your explanation. I understand how it works. How do you actually think of this solution? Do you write in a piece of paper?

Comment: The loop algorithms come to me, when I have to do complicated nested loops I ussually write them down on paper so I don't forget them. Practice is the best way to "master" loops (I did a lot when I was studying).

Comment: Does anyone know where can i get java practices on looping questions? I'm always stucked on answering a new looping question. Thank you!

Comment: [Here](http://www.shenet.org/high/hsacaddept/technology/chanley/javahalfyear/assigns/Spring2010/Java%20Assignment3-LoopPractice.pdf) and [Here](http://www.bowdoin.edu/~ltoma/teaching/cs107/fall05/Lectures-Handouts/for.pdf) are some, try to search "loop java practices filetype:pdf" in google, also reading other people's code helps.